# Bad caret position message

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextfield, getcaretpos

Here's a message I am plagued by, which occurs when I attempt to programmatically "select" cells (whether empty or not) in a `grid` via keypress combo `shift-rightarrow` or `shift-leftarrow`:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.swing.text.StateInvariantError: 
Bad caret position
```

(Note that there is NO problem if I "select" via `shift-uparrow` or `shift-downarrow`.)

It happens when I attempt to change the font of the "selected" cells:

```
  static Font fontSelected = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD , POINTSIZE);
  static Font fontNormal = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, POINTSIZE);
```

*(If I make the Font.type the **SAME** (both BOLD, both PLAIN, both ITALIC), **no problem**.)*

The error occurs near code where I `push` a "selected" `JTextField` onto a stack (named `stack`), which is defined like so:

```
class GenericStack<E>:
  public LinkedList <E> stack = new LinkedList<>();
```

Here's the class declaration where the stack and fonts are used:

```
public class Grid  extends GenericStack<JTextField> implements ActionListener, KeyListener, KeyCodes, Serializable
```

Here's what's pushed onto `stack`:

```
 public static JTextField[][] cells = new JTextField[N][N];
```

Here's how `cells` are created:

```
    guiFrame.add(textPanel);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
      for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
        cells[i][j] = addCell(textPanel, i, j);

  private JTextField addCell (Container parent, int row, int col) {
    JTextField cell;
    cell = new JTextField();
    cell.setFont(fontNormal);                  // 'default' font set
    cell.setText("x");                         // for debugging
    String r, c;                               // 11x11 grid
    if(row < N-1) r = "" + row; else r = "A";  // rows  r: 0,1,2,...A
    if(col < N-1) c = "" + col; else c = "A";  // cols  c: 0,1,2,...A
    cell.setActionCommand(r + c);              // cell rc: 00..0A;10..1A;...A0..AA;
    cell.addKeyListener(this);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    parent.add(cell);
    return cell;
  }
```

Here's main:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {    
     javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        new Grid();
      }
    });
  }
```

Here's where the font is changed (for any "selected" cell):

```
if(currentCell.selected){
  Grid.cells[currentCell.row][currentCell.col].setBackground(Color.RED);
  Grid.cells[currentCell.row][currentCell.col].setFont(fontSelected);
  stack.push(Grid.cells[currentCell.row][currentCell.col]);
}
```

The error occurs in this block of code--if I comment out the `setFont` line, no problem; if I instead change the font declarations to involve the same font, no problem.

Especially puzzling me is that the stack trace doesn't specify which line of code caused the error.

Comment: If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or local images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Google shows this: "Bug 81777 - javax.swing.text.StateInvariantError: Bad caret position... resolved fixed ... 2006 ...2008 ... Hardware: ... Mac OS X" as well as this:

Subject: [Bug 236459] New: Bad caret position permalink
From: ekan...@netbeans.org (ekan...@netbeans.org)
Date: Sep 27, 2013 3:34:13 am
List: org.netbeans.classfile.issues

So maybe I'm just screwed??

But I'll do what "Eels" just suggested, I guess. Or maybe just use a different "selection" method.

Comment: Again, for the best chances of us understanding your problem and *experiencing* your problem, post an [sscce](http://sscce.org). You've nothing to lose in the effort.

Comment: Will do. I guess if it's a bug and not just me, the Java community will profit, so I'm on it.

Comment: I'll up-vote you for the effort and for my opportunity to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why your exception is occurring, but it can be solved by queuing the font change on the Swing event thread:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
  final JComponent comp = (JComponent) evt.getSource();
  int keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
  boolean shiftIsDown = evt.isShiftDown();
  currentCell.selected = ((shiftIsDown & (keyCode == RIGHT | keyCode == UP
        | keyCode == LEFT | keyCode == DOWN)));
  if (currentCell.selected) {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           comp.setFont(fontSelected);
        }
     });
  }
}
```

Myself, I try to avoid KeyListeners with Swing applications but instead prefer key bindings. For example:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SSCCE2 extends JPanel {
   private static final int ROW_COUNT = 11;
   private static final int colCount = 3;
   private static final Font NORMAL_FONT = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18);
   private static final Font SELECTED_FONT = NORMAL_FONT.deriveFont(Font.BOLD);

   private JTextField[][] fields = new JTextField[ROW_COUNT][ROW_COUNT];

   public SSCCE2() {
      FontAction fontAction = new FontAction();
      int condition = WHEN_FOCUSED;

      setLayout(new GridLayout(ROW_COUNT, ROW_COUNT));
      for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < fields[i].length; j++) {
            JTextField cell = new JTextField(colCount);
            InputMap inputMap = cell.getInputMap(condition);
            ActionMap actionMap = cell.getActionMap();
            int[] arrowKeyCodes = {KeyEvent.VK_UP, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 
                  KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT};
            for (int keyCode : arrowKeyCodes) {
               KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 
                     KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK);
               inputMap.put(keyStroke, keyStroke.toString());
               actionMap.put(keyStroke.toString(), fontAction);
            }
            cell.setFont(NORMAL_FONT);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
            add(cell);
            fields[i][j] = cell;
         }
      }


   }

   private class FontAction extends AbstractAction {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         for (JTextField[] row : fields) {
            for (JTextField textField : row) {
               if (textField.hasFocus()) {
                  textField.setFont(SELECTED_FONT);
               } else {
                  textField.setFont(NORMAL_FONT);
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SSCCE2 mainPanel = new SSCCE2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed everything, including cursor movement code, that didn't affect getting the message, so when this is run, a grid appears, and to get the error, hold the shift key down and press right arrow key. (Is this what I should've done??) (P.S.--I even took out all the generic linked list (stack) stuff, which, it turns out, had nothing to do with the problem.)

```
package sscce;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class Cell 
{
  int row, col;
  boolean selected;

  Cell(int row, int col){
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;  
  } 
}

public class SSCCE implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{
  public static final int LEFT = 37, UP = 38, RIGHT = 39, DOWN = 40;
  public static final int N = 11;
  JFrame guiFrame;
  JPanel textPanel;
  public static JTextField[][] cells = new JTextField[N][N];
  public static Cell currentCell = new Cell(0,0);

  static Font fontSelected = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD , 12);
  static Font fontNormal = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12);

  public SSCCE(){ 
    textPanel = new JPanel();
    textPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(N, N));
    guiFrame = new JFrame();
    guiFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);    
    guiFrame.add(textPanel);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
      for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
        cells[i][j] = addCell(textPanel, i, j);
    guiFrame.setVisible(true);
  }  

  private JTextField addCell (Container parent, int row, int col) {
    JTextField cell;
    cell = new JTextField();
    cell.setFont(fontNormal);
    cell.addKeyListener((KeyListener) this);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    parent.add(cell);
    return cell;
  }  

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {    
     javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        new SSCCE();
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) { 
    int keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
    boolean shiftIsDown = evt.isShiftDown();
    currentCell.selected = ((shiftIsDown & (keyCode == RIGHT | keyCode == UP | keyCode == LEFT | keyCode == DOWN)));
    if(currentCell.selected ){
      SSCCE.cells[currentCell.row][currentCell.col].setFont(fontSelected);
    }
   }
  @Override
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){     }
  @Override
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){  }
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){}
}
```

Comment: Ah. "Key binding". New concept. Guess I DON'T know it all. (Ha.) Does my problem have anything to do with the fact that, as Java has told me over and over, "Warning: Swing is not thread safe. For more information see Swing's Threading Policy," which I've never done. And does your code (below) answer that question?                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()

Comment: THANKS, EELS, for not only taking interest in MY problem (i.e., not a Java bug) AND for not only FIXING it but designing alternative code that, while I assure you I can't quite follow it, I will study it later. YOU ROCK!! (Ah! Unless I'm mistaken, I just "got" your name! "I have had it with these goshdarned eels on this goshdarned hovercraft!")(A bonus: laughter!!)